# Changing window.location.href in Firefox in response to an onunload event

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, window.location

I have a strange JavaScript problem using `window.location.href`, which apparently only affects Firefox (I'm using 3.6).

Normally `window.location.href` would not be read-only, and this works perfectly in Firefox:

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com/";
```

However, when I call a function in response to an `onunload` event (`<body onunload="testThis();">`), this doesn't work as expected:

```
function testThis() {
    alert ("1: " + window.location.href);
    window.location.href = "http://google.com/";
    alert ("2: " + window.location.href);
    return false;
}
```

In both cases, the alert displays the current location of the page in Firefox, without making the change. There are no JavaScript errors, and the `onunload` event successfully calls the function, so the problem appears to be editing or replacing the value of `window.location.href`.

I've tried using `window.location`, `document.location.href`, even tried changing `window.location.search`. Is it possible that an event, specifically an `onunload` event, causes `window.location.href` to become read-only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, to prevent malicious webpages from blocking the user from leaving.

Comment: And I for one am very grateful for that :-)

Comment: Is the same true of onbeforeunload?

Comment: I think so. I also think that you can return a string which is then displayed in a confirm dialog (let's the user confirm the navigate-away or cancel/stay).

Comment: There can be many reasons to prevent a user from using the back button, like preventing users from resubmitting forms (sloppy programming) or like clients armed with a little knowledge insisting that their intranet users not be able to return to previous pages once they start a test or a survey. I'll leave it up to your collective imagination which one applies here...

Is there any documentation available on which events prevent window properties from being edited? And on which browsers are affected?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload ``There is no public specification. onbeforeunload was introduced by Microsoft IE 4 and has subsequently been copied by other browsers. ´´

Answer (score 0):

For the record, firefox seems to use document.location in lieu of document.location.href.